# Can i use Glide to cache images without displaying them

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-glide

I have a feed that sends me the list of `logos`

```
{
  "logos": {
    "GoogleLogo": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEC8Plg0onmk5-0lHzN74023FJaH_N_4prUSlBBaUR9FqmjbfVhA"
  }
}
```

There are around 30 Logos that this feed sends me.

What i want to do is to to hit this service when user launches the app for the first time, and cache all the images by using `Glide`.

So in app whenever i use following method, it won't hit the service, and display the images right away to user.

```
  GlideApp
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .into(myImageView);
```

I will be creating a `HashMap<String, String>` that will have `logo name` as key and its `URL` as value.

My Question is that is there any method available in Glide which can be used to cache images without displaying them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using **FutureTarget** you can load image in Background.

start Intent Service and load images in `onHandleIntent` method. Like,

```
String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("res");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            if (common.getNetworkType().equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
                stopSelf();
                break;
            } else {
                JSONObject jObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(this).load(common.completeURL(jObj.getString("AvatarImage"))).downloadOnly(400, 400);
                try {
                    future.get();
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    stopSelf();
                    break;
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    stopSelf();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stopSelf();
        logger.w(TAG, "onHandleIntent: ", e);
    }
```